# modeler client throwing Java memory error

Tags: sql, db2

I have a question related to IBM Data Studio Client 4.1.1 (Enterprise Edition) java heap space error. On running certain `select * from` queries, the client crashes and generates a heap file giving Java heap space error. I thought this issue might be resolved by increasing Java heap space, but I have already 1 GB of Java heap space allocated, and have 8GB of RAM in my system. I researched on the issue and found IBM document which is listed here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21486423

To put it all together, I run a simple `select * from` query, the client brings up error message '**java heap space**' and a dump file is created on my computer in the *program files> IBM > SDP* folder. I seeked help from the IT team in my organization and nobody could figure out the issue, they kept reinstalling a different version of the client on the same workspace and settings because whenever I reopened the application after a new installation, all configurations and settings even the code I last wrote was retained as is, so maybe reinstallation is not the solution to my problem. How should I pursue this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio (which is based on the Eclipse IDE platform) is quite memory-hungry; 1 GB of heap is rarely enough, particularly if you want to retrieve large datasets, which must be stored in the Eclipse memory in their entirety. I suggest you allocate 3-4 GB to Data Studio: find the file called `eclipse.ini` in the Data Studio installation directory, open it with a text editor and modify the line that starts with `-Xmx` to read for example `-Xmx3500m`, then (re)start the program.

Comment: Is there any other way i can increase the java heap space memory. I am not  sure if it is a myth, but i have heard from my co-workers that increasing memory through eclipse.ini some times create issues.....

Comment: It's a myth, and there's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the default limits for number of rows returned in the SQL Results View?

The default is that Data Studio will only fetch the first 500 rows from your query, so if your query returns thousands (or more) rows and Data Studio is trying to fetch and display all of them it will require a *lot* of memory.

This setting is configurable in `Preferences > SQL Development > SQL Results View Options`.

Comment: So, perhaps try setting it to something a lot smaller.  Are you *really* going to page through 50,000 rows returned from the database?!  Or, increase memory significantly as @mustaccio suggests.

Comment: Actually i need to return that many rows for a query that customer requires.